# Call Helper methods in phtml file Custom Module in Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, helper, system-config

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php`

```
   <?php
namespace Custommodule\ReviewRating\Block;

class HomehorizontalWidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $_helper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = [],
    \Custommodule\ReviewRating\Helper\Data $helper
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

    $this->_helper = $helper;
}


    public function getEnable(){
        return $this->_helper->getEnable();
    }

}
```

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/view/frontend/templates/homehorizontalwidget.phtml`

```
<?php  echo $block->getEnable(); ?>
```

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php 
namespace Custommodule_ReviewRating\ReviewRating\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper { 

    /** * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterfac 
        */ 
    protected $_scopeConfig; 
    CONST ENABLE = 'reviewrating/general/enable_module'; 


    public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context, 
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig ) {

             parent::__construct($context); $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getEnable(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::ENABLE);
    }


}
```

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
system configuration labels created.
```

> Error : 
>   3 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Custommodule\ReviewRating\Block\HomehorizontalWidget
>   Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Custommodule\ReviewRating\Helper\Data does not exist
>   Exception #2 (ReflectionException): Class Custommodule\ReviewRating\Helper\Data does not exist
>
> I followed this article [how-to-create-a-magento-2-extension](https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-create-a-magento-2-extension/)

UPDATE:: Issue resolved i have to change the namespace in `In /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/Helper/Data.php` as suggested @Rakesh Jesadiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just redeclare Custommodule_ReviewRating in your path instead of just one,

```
   <?php 
    namespace Custommodule\ReviewRating\Helper;

    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper { 

        /** * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterfac 
            */ 
        protected $_scopeConfig; 
        CONST ENABLE = 'reviewrating/general/enable_module'; 


        public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $contex

t, 
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig ) {

             parent::__construct($context); $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getEnable(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::ENABLE);
    }


}
```

Comment: var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/Helper/Data.php  

I changed the class name as ` namespace Custommodule\ReviewRating\Helper;` now its working fine.

Thnak You